# Inverse of this floor function exists

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions, inverse-function

Fix an $ a \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \backslash \ \left \{\tfrac{2M+1}{2N+1} : M,N \in \mathbb{N}\right \}   $, and define $ f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R} $ by:
\begin{equation}
   f(m) =  m + \lfloor a m - \tfrac{a}{2} + \tfrac12  \rfloor.
 \end{equation}

Because of the constraint on a, I claim that $ f $ has a left inverse, given by:

\begin{equation}\label{key}
 f^{-1}(m)= \lfloor  \tfrac{m}{1+a} + \tfrac12 \rfloor.
\end{equation}

I was wondering if there is a quick way to check this.

Comment: Where did $k$ come from?